# Finding View in Android

Tags: java, android, view

I am writing an application cooking.... i want to design my application similar like this picture.

[image]

I have marked this picture with red square. I wonder what type of view it is ? Are these buttons designed by Graphic Designer or Is it available in available views ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), specifically a `TabPageIndicator`. You can use a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and a `ViewPager` in order to be able to swipe left and right - very cool!

For example:

[image: Beautiful Widgets example]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android Action-Bar (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). It is a device independent action bar where you can add tabs and define actions. It's automatically adapted to the device where your app runs.

With the Action-Bar you can define whether some of the actions should be displayed on the bottom in case of narrow devices. And it also handles nicely the menu button (or no menu button) with an overflow (3 dots) action which displays actions which are not visible due to missing space.

Answer (score 0):

Or use TabActivty and style your tabs by yourself.

Here is documentation of TabActivity
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html